# My Regex aint working, help me figure out what I did wrong

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a particular data from a data string, I created a regex patter for it but it doesn't work, could anyone point out what I did wrong here.

The Data String:

```
    Wed, September 7th, 11:06am - Case Lead ID: #260-A53-0C4C
John Doe | johndoe@gmail.com | 123456789
```

The Data I am trying to extract is the Case Lead ID and this is the regex pattern I used

```
 Case Lead ID: #:\n(.+)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `:\n`, use

```
Case Lead ID: #(.+)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Ac5LDb/1).

Comment: Thanks it worked, btw why didn't /n work?

Comment: @fahadsheji \n is a line feed. It is not present in the string.